# Tables selected row for JAWS reader

Tags: html, accessibility, selected, jaws-screen-reader

I've a table where there's a CSS class for the selected row.
Which is the attribute to make reader like JAWS find the selected row in a table and read it ?
And when this should happen (when the table is located or there's a keyboard combo) ?

Comment: There is no attribute that does this as far as I am aware? It is also unclear exactly what you mean by "find the selected row in the table" as tables don't have selected rows? Do you mean where the virtual cursor currently is? Could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve / what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Do you mean `aria-selected` just as a side thought, as that doesn't work well on tables (it might kind of work on `role="grid"` but would be inconsistent)?

Comment: there's just a CSS for the selected row

Comment: So you're trying to set focus on a table row? Is that correct? The question is difficult to understand.

Comment: I was trying to make the screen reader find the selected row and read "selected". It seems it's working now with the suggestion by @GrahamRitchie putting role="grid" on table tag and aria-selected="true" on the row

Comment: Technically speaking, it's not correct to use `role='grid'` on a standard table unless you intend for it to be a data cell layout similar to a spreadsheet. A screen reader like JAWS will interpret the `role='grid'` property and apply arrow key navigation to the table, which is not what a JAWS user would expect with a regular table.

Comment: If the table row is "selected", then presumably the user has to perform an action to select the row (such as click the row or press enter on the highlighted row)? If so, my suggestion would be to add a control such as a checkbox or radio button in the first column so screen readers will announce that the row is selected, rather than messing with the table's role.